# use systemd to mount sshfs

Tags: mount, systemd, ubuntu-core, sshfs, fuse

I am running Ubuntu Core on my Raspberry Pi and I would like to map a drive connected to a local server.

On other devices I use the `sshfs` to map this drive locally and it works.

However on Ubuntu Core for armhf the sshfs is not installed and I could not find a snap to install it.

To solve this I tried to mount using systemd. The content of the `home-localuser-remotedata.mount` file looks like this:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Mount unit for data

[Mount] 
What=sftpuser@192.168.24.136:/
Where=/home/localuser /remotedata
Type=fuse.sshfs
Options=umask=0007,uid=1000,gid=1000,Port=65000,IdentityFile=/home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

to make things simple I tried first with an ssh id that is not protected by passphrase

Mounting with systemd usb connceted drives works just fine.

Has anyone tried this before?
Will systemd mount if sshfs is not installed?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Will systemd mount if sshfs is not installed? No, systemd does not implement sshfs by itself.

Comment: Answer no! `apt install sshfs`